# What is a better way of calling a multi dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I'm brand new  Java and received a coding project from my instructor. I'm creating a Java program that will help someone if they were traveling to another country. Right now I'm stuck on trying to find a better way to translate a phrase from English to one of the languages listed in the multi dimensional array I created. Sorry that this post is long. This is my second time ever using stack overflow in months.

```
String[][] Phrases = 
{{"Hola", "Adios", "Gracias", "Si", "No", "Lo siento or perdón"},//Spanish
{"Bonjour", "Goodbye", "Au revoir", "Oui", "Non", "Je suis désolé"},//French
{"Merhaba", "Güle güle", "teşekkür ederim", "Evet", "yok hayır", "üzgünüm"},//Turkish
{"Здравствуйте (Zdravstvuyte)", "Прощай (Proshchay)", "Спасибо (Spasibo)", "да (da)", "нет (net)", "прости (prosti)"}};//Russian
```

I have a switch statement and in case 4 I was going to do if statements to call on the array to translate the English's phrases based on the user's input. It works fine for translating it to Spanish, but that's a lot to do if I gotta do it for the other three languages.

```
switch (option){




    case 4: System.out.println("Select which phrase 1 through 6 you would like to translate to.");
        System.out.println("1 - Hello, \n2 - Goodbye, \n3 - Thank you, \n4 - Yes, \n5 - No, \n6 - I'm Sorry");
        int speak = 0;
        speak = info.nextInt();

         if (speak ==1){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][0]);
    } else if (speak == 2){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][1]);
    }else if (speak == 3){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][2]);
    }else if (speak == 4){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][3]);
    }else if (speak == 5){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][4]);
    }


           break;

    //Give user menu of phrases, store phrase input, call array for phrase,
}
```

There's definitely a better way of doing this than writing a bunch of if statements. What is a better way on calling on the array to translate the phrase that the user wants to translate? I apologize if this isn't making any sense, but at this point I'm completely lost. Below is everything that I got so far. I'm using Blue J and I have two classes. All I'm looking to do is find a simpler way of translating the English phrases to one of the four languages provided when the user chooses which phrase to translate to.

Travle Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Travel
{


public static void main (String args[]) {
System.out.println("Welcome to One Culture! Before selecting a vacation spot, we'll need to ask a few things.");
//User input
System.out.println("What's your full name?");
Scanner info = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = info.nextLine();

System.out.println("What's your nationality?");
String origin = info.nextLine();

System.out.println("Are you looking for a place where the weather is hot or cold?");
String temp = info.nextLine();

System.out.println("How much money do you plan on traveling with? What's your budget?");
int money = info.nextInt();

System.out.println("Traveler's Information: \n" + "Name: " + name + "\nOrigin: " + origin +
"\nBudget: " + money +" USD" + "\nPreferred Weather: " + temp + "\n");


System.out.println("Based on traveler's information, here are locations of interest: \n");

Assistant.vacationSpot();
int spot = 0;
if (temp.equals ("hot")){
    System.out.println("\nBased on weather choice, here are recommended locations for hot: ");
    Assistant.warm();
    System.out.println("\nUse the following codes to input your currency choices for your destination: \n 1 - Mexican peso \n 2 - Senegal West African CFA franc");
        spot = info.nextInt();
}
        else if(temp.equals ("cold")){
    System.out.println("\nBased on weather choice, here are recommended locations for cold: ");
    Assistant.cold();
    System.out.println("\nUse the following codes to input your currency choices for your destination: \n 3 - Turkish Lira \n 4 - Russian ruble");
         spot = info.nextInt();
    }



int option = 0;  

//Greeting user
String greet = "";
if (spot == 1) {
         greet = "Mexico";
     }
     else if (spot == 2){
         greet = "Senegal";
        }
     else if (spot == 3){
         greet = "Turkey";
        }   

     else if (spot == 4){
         greet = "Russia";
        }



String[] moneySwap = {"peso", "CFA franc", "Lira", "ruble"};




/*String[] spanishPhrases = {"Hola", "Adios", "Gracias", "Si", "No", "Lo siento or perdón"}; 
String[] frenchPhrases = {"Bonjour", "Goodbye", "Au revoir", "Oui", "Non", "Je suis désolé"};
String[] turkishPhrases = {"Merhaba", "Güle güle", "teşekkür ederim", "Evet", "yok hayır", "üzgünüm"};
String[] russianPhrases = {"Здравствуйте (Zdravstvuyte)", "Прощай (Proshchay)", "Спасибо (Spasibo)", "да (da)", "нет (net)", "прости (prosti)"};
 */

String[][] Phrases = 
{{"Hola", "Adios", "Gracias", "Si", "No", "Lo siento or perdón"},//Spanish
{"Bonjour", "Goodbye", "Au revoir", "Oui", "Non", "Je suis désolé"},//French
{"Merhaba", "Güle güle", "teşekkür ederim", "Evet", "yok hayır", "üzgünüm"},//Turkish
{"Здравствуйте (Zdravstvuyte)", "Прощай (Proshchay)", "Спасибо (Spasibo)", "да (da)", "нет (net)", "прости (prosti)"}};//Russian


System.out.println("Welcome to " + greet + " What would you like to do now?");

//Menu of task to perform
System.out.println("1 - convert currency \n 2 - Haggle prices \n 3 - Make a purchase \n 4 - Translate a phrase.");
option = info.nextInt();


switch (option){
    case 1: System.out.println("Your budget from USD to " + moneySwap[spot - 1] + " is " +  Assistant.currency(money, spot));
            break;

    case 2:
            break;

    case 3: //ask user for purchase cost, store number, subtract from total budget, check if budget is less than 0
            break;

    case 4: System.out.println("Select which phrase 1 through 6 you would like to translate to.");
        System.out.println("1 - Hello, \n2 - Goodbye, \n3 - Thank you, \n4 - Yes, \n5 - No, \n6 - I'm Sorry");
        int speak = 0;
        speak = info.nextInt();

         if (speak ==1){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][0]);
    } else if (speak == 2){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][1]);
    }else if (speak == 3){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][2]);
    }else if (speak == 4){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][3]);
    }else if (speak == 5){
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][4]);
    }


           break;

    //Give user menu of phrases, store phrase input, call array for phrase,
}
 }
}
```

Below this is the Assistant

```
   public class Assistant
{

 //Displaying warm locations
 public static void warm() {
 String[][] warm = {{"Mexico","Senegal"},
                   {"Spanish", "French"}};
            hot(warm);       
            }                      
 public static void hot(String x[][]){
     for(int row = 0; row < x.length; row++){
         for (int col = 0; col < x[row].length;col++){
            System.out.print(x[row][col]+ "\t");
         }
         System.out.println();
        }              
   }  

 //Displaying colder locations
 public static void cold() {
 String[][] freeze = {{"Turkey ","Russia"},
                     {"Turkish","Russian",}};  
            display(freeze);       
            }                      
 public static void freeze(String x[][]){
     for(int row = 0; row < x.length; row++){
         for (int col = 0; col < x[row].length;col++){
            System.out.print(x[row][col]+ "\t");
         }
         System.out.println();
        }                 
   }  

   //money conversion
 public static double currency(int budget, int  dest) {
     double temp = budget;
     if (dest == 1) {
         temp = budget * 18.84;
     }
     else if (dest == 2){
         temp = budget * 543.75;
        }
     else if (dest == 3){
         temp = budget * 4.10;
        }   

      else if (dest == 4){
         temp = budget * 63.42;
        }
     return temp;
    }












}
```

Comment: Maps are used for this purpose, however since you have not learned them, your prof likely has got you doing this.

Comment: I tried the two solutions given to me below and they worked, but only when translating the phrases to Spanish. How do I get it to translate to the other languages if the user selected one of the other three countries?

Answer (score 2):

You already have the index of the translation that you want to return. You don't need `if` statements at all.

Replace:

```
         if (speak ==1){
    System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][0]);
} else if (speak == 2){
    System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][1]);
}else if (speak == 3){
    System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][2]);
}else if (speak == 4){
    System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][3]);
}else if (speak == 5){
    System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][4]);
}
```

With:

```
if(speak > 0 && speak < 5){
    System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][speak-1]);
}else{
    //handle the invalid input however you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your speak integer represents one more than the index for that word, so access the word using speak - 1:

```
case 4: System.out.println("Select which phrase 1 through 6 you would like to translate to.");
        System.out.println("1 - Hello, \n2 - Goodbye, \n3 - Thank you, \n4 - Yes, \n5 - No, \n6 - I'm Sorry");
        int speak = 0;
        speak = info.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][speak-1]
```

If using this method, it would be smart to use an extra if statement to check that speak is between 1 and 5 too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone that helped out and posted their solutions. I took what I saw from the two who posted their answer and the solution worked, but only when translating to Spanish. I needed it to be able to translate the phrases depending on which of the four locations the user was in. So I added a few if statements and got this...

```
 if(spot == 1 && speak > 0 && speak < 7){
      System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[0][speak-1]);
     }else if ((spot == 2 && speak > 0 && speak < 7)) {         
         System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[1][speak-1]);
         //handle the invalid input however you want
      } else if ((spot == 3 && speak > 0 && speak < 7)) {         
         System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[2][speak-1]);

        }else if ((spot == 4 && speak > 0 && speak < 7)) {         
         System.out.println("Option " + speak + " translates to " + Phrases[3][speak-1]);
        }
```

I just added `spot` into the if statements so it would know which country the user selected and translate it to that specific language. I then made `speak < 7` because it wasn't translating the phrases option 5 and 6. Still new to this, but when I tell how excited I was when I figured it out, I was pretty happy.